# Develop an option pricing equation by Ornstein Uhlenbeck process

Tags: black-scholes, ornstein-uhlenbeck

I know that Black-Scholes equation is based that the Equity price has a Geometrical Brownian movement.
Can I develop from the same principles( now with transaction cost) that Black Scholes is developed an eqution that  the equity price is based on the Ornstein Uhlenbeck process? 
Thanks

Comment: This is too general. What is motivation for such modeling choice? What is the economic or financial sense of the model? What would you like to achieve, and what are your assumptions?

Comment: The  Ornstein Uhlenbeck process has the mean reversion property that geometric Brownian does not has

Comment: I'm not sure if this is valid but you can try setting up a hedging portfolio consisting of a short position in the option, delta shares of the stock, and a position in the money market. The infinitesimal P&L of this portfolio should be $0$, which gives the Black Scholes PDE. So you can do something similar using the OU process but now there will be a source term from the drift.

Comment: Can you use the Giranov theorem to change the measure and make a Martingale?

Comment: Are you looking for a Black&Scholes-style "closed form" option pricer or just any numerical approach will do? You can do OU dynamics with transaction costs very easily in FDM for example

Comment: Simulate paths. Average the payoff if positive. Discount and you have the option prices. The real problem is dealing with OU parameters proper values.

Comment: I want to develop a differential equation and after that solve it and see how the mean reversion property of Ornstein  Uhlenbeck affect the option value.

Comment: Lisa Ann: I want a closed solution and not to use the martingale representation theorem .